# Content type in call to web service

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

Please correct me if I'm wrong in defining contet type:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{"my_id":"975","my_a_id":"Test66","param":"4","amount":"66"}
```

and

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
my_id=123&my_a_id=Test66&param=4&amount=66
```

What other content types might be?

What content type supports `RESTLet` `NetSuite` services?

I have POST to web service:

```
POST https://some.netsuite.uri?deploy=1 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_account=3624292_SB3, nlauth_email=xduh31@gmail.com, nlauth_signature=Pass987654, nlauth_role=3
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: rest.eu1.netsuite.com
Cookie: JSESSIONID=**************************************; lastUser=1234567_SB9_1282_3; NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING; NS_VER=2017.1.0
Content-Length: 69
Expect: 100-continue

{"my_id":"975","my_a_id":"Test66","param":"4","amount":"66"}
```

Is it good that in URL I have something like `x-www-form-urlencoded` - `?deploy=1`

```
https://some.netsuite.uri?deploy=1
```

and data is `json` style:

```
{"my_id":"975","my_a_id":"Test66","param":"4","amount":"66"}
```

UPD

I got answer that I suppose should return `JSON` data:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 03 Jun 2017 06:21:46 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: No-Cache
Pragma: No-Cache
Content-Length: 41
Expires: 0
Edge-Control: no-store
X-N-OperationId: 486c2d20-099d-446b-9788-4816db59a1fd
Set-Cookie: .......................; path=/
NS_RTIMER_COMPOSITE: 1688996695:706172746E6572733030312E70726F642E6475622E6E65746C65646765722E636F6D:80
P3P: CP="CAO PSAa OUR BUS PUR"
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@54b896b0
```

But this answer not looks like JSON?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for that REST API? It should all be documented

Comment: I don't have documentation of current service. I have just sample call wit GET call. I decided that GET is not nice when posting data and decide to find method to call with POST

Comment: @vico you should not share your user credentials with us :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be your URL. Have you tried changing

```
https://some.netsuite.uri&deploy=1
```

to

```
https://some.netsuite.uri?deploy=1
```

**Edit:**

Also, your Accept header says you are looking for an application/json response, is that what the server is returning?

Comment: you are right - I have done mistake by placing '&' instead of '?' when hiding real address.

Comment: I have updated my question body with answer I got from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can find supported content types in NS Help Center:

> RESTlets support JSON and plain text content types for input and
>   output. For each RESTlet, output content type is the same as input
>   content type.
>
> You must set the content type in the HTTP Content-Type header. You can
>   use the following values to specify the input/output content type for
>   a RESTlet:
>
> application/json
>
> text/plain
>
> If you specify a content type other than JSON or text, a 415 error is
>   returned with the following message:
>
> Invalid content type.  You can only use application/json or text/plain
>   with RESTlets.

[Documentation](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n2972591.html)

Besides that the issue in the url mentioned by shazmodan, the script Id is missing. Below is an example of a valid restlet url:

```
https://rest.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?deploy=1&script=1
```

You can pass additional parameters in the url:

```
https://rest.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?deploy=1&script=1&my_id=123&my_a_id=Test66&param=4&amount=66
```

or in the request body if you are using `POST` and `PUT` methods but it needs to be a valid JSON. But the Content Type must always be `application/json` or `text/plain`.